# mod_rewrite - Only use whatever is after the last forward slash

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

So I already have my .htaccess file configured so that when I load the webpage (http://example.com/about), it transparently redirects it to http://example.com/about.html, however, I'd like it now to be able to do (http://example.com/about/contact), then have it transparently redirect to http://example.com/about/contact.html. I guess ideally it'd completely ignore the "/about/" part of the URL and only use the contact part.

This is what I'm using right now:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# folder/file => folder/file.html
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9_\-]+)/([a-z0-9_\-]+)/?$ $2.html [NC,L]

# file => file.html
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9_\-]+)/?$ $1.html [NC,L]
```

Comment: That almost works but the thing is all the files sit in the root directory, so contact.html isn't in an /about/ directory. So when I go to example.com/about/contact, it should load contact.html from the root directory

Comment: Oh I see, I updated my answer - That will affect All sub-folder. If you have sub-folder that really exists you will need to specify them

Comment: Awesome, that works. I have a subdirectory called "i", how would I declare that in the .htaccess? Thanks

Comment: Yes you can. Or you create a rule that ignore if the request is "/i/..."